# document.getElementById gotcha - no need declaring element?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, getelementbyid

I came across the following gotcha I can't seem to wrap my head around.

Say I want to set the `innerHTML` of a `div` with the `#show5` id via Javascript.

```
var show5 = document.getElementById('show5');
show5.innerHTML = 'matthew mcconaughhey';
```

The code above makes sense: first you assign the `div` to `show5`, and then you set the `innerHTML` of `show5`. Nothing special here.

However, I noticed that even if I leave out the first line, the code still works. Console doesn't even show any errors:

```
// var show5 = document.getElementById('show5'); - commented out
show5.innerHTML = 'matthew mcconaughhey';
```

You'd expect the code to fail here. But it is working. Can anyone explain to me why this is or is there something wrong with the logic on my part?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eyK8w/1/)

Comment: This is expected, elements are global on the window object based on ID's etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE/Chrome: are DOM tree elements global variables here?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/ie-chrome-are-dom-tree-elements-global-variables-here)

Comment: @adeneo you're right. didn't realize that. thanks though! :)